# Apache2 keeps rewriting https even though rewrite rules are removed

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

I am running multiple virtual hosts on a local machine running Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache2. Let's assume that the project I am trying to access has the ServerName directive set to `website.local`
When I try to access it in the browser with `website.local` the browser is immediately redirected to `https://website.local` and then fails to connect.

I think I found a potential cause but I am not sure. When I first setup the project it contained an `.htaccess` file with the following rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

these were in place from the production environment. I removed them but the issue persisted.

As a test I setup a new virtual host `test.local` pointing to the same project directory, but this time I made sure that the rewrite rules were not there before enabling the virtual host in Apache. This time the project loaded without a problem at `test.local`.

It seems then in my limited experience, that Apache is somehow 'remembering' the rewrite rules for the old virtual host. I tried disabling and enabling the host and reloading Apache but no dice.

Is my suggestion indeed the problem and so how do I fix it? Or am I completely missing the real underlying issue here

Comment: Maybe a browser cache issue ?

Comment: Spot on! As I feared, I was over analyzing this and looking in all the wrong directions

Comment: Browser cache is most of the time a problem when debugging Web Apps. **Always clear the cache between each tests** :)

Comment: Another source for this behavior might be HSTS header sent by the server, which tells the client to always use https in the future when contacting the server.